# MVC Core Set IHostingEnvironment to Development

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How Do I manually set the IhostingEnvironment env to development? I would like to use C# code to do this, not command line.

Thanks,

```
   public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the env.EnvironmentName to "Development" in the Startup method.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    env.EnvironmentName = "Development";  // <- Set the EnvironmentName to "Development"

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
```

And if you see the implementation of `IsDevelopment` method at [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/cad9ea1df7e78c52c99346de17b6fc3c2bc2c67e/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions/HostingEnvironmentExtensions.cs) (github repo), you will observe that it works based on string compare operation for `EnvironmentName`.

```
    public static bool IsDevelopment(this IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        if (hostingEnvironment == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hostingEnvironment));
        }

        return hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development);
    }


    public static bool IsEnvironment(
        this IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
        string environmentName)
    {
        if (hostingEnvironment == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hostingEnvironment));
        }

        return string.Equals(
            hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName,
            environmentName,
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that, _ihostingenvironment.Object.EnvironmentName = "Development"; using nunit with Moq, got this error, I will have to figure it out,  "System.nullreferenceexception. Object reference not set to instance of object, "

Comment: Null reference exception you might be getting due to null value of _ihostingenvironment.Object. Can you check the value in debugger. If it's null then you are not mocking it appropriately.

Comment: yep, I am getting that, trying to fix it, '_ihostingenvironment.Object' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'"         Mock<IHostingEnvironment> _ihostingenvironment;
        Mock<Startup> _startup;               _ihostingenvironment.Object.EnvironmentName = "Development";

Comment: won't even let me set the equal set operation

Comment: Not sure about your comment ---won't even let me set the equal set operation. `EnvriormentName` is defined as get and set. Check the definition at https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/cad9ea1df7e78c52c99346de17b6fc3c2bc2c67e/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions/IHostingEnvironment.cs